# using value of boolean to display information

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have a `bool` that could either be `true` or `false` and display different messages depending on the `bool` value using the `?` and `:`

I tried below

```
Message = if(isPGUID = true) "ParentGuide" else "Guid is not the parent Guid",
```

Comment: Maybe this `Message = isPGUID ? "ParentGuide" : "Guid is not the parent Guid";` ???

Comment: @AlessandroD'Andria thanks, if you can have it as an answer to mark that would be great

Comment: @AlessandroD'Andria: should use "==" and not "=".

Comment: @ShellShock absolutely right!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably mean:

```
Message = isPGUID ? "ParentGuide" : "Guid is not the parent Guid";
```

Though your question could use  a bit of clarification.